# How to handle Eclipse console input and output (Java)?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, console

I have a Java application run eclipse, user could input and output by "console"; in the meantime, I want to use another application to handle the "console", for example, another Java application to input "text string" into console, and then output saved into file. I am sorry firstly for the confusing question, do someone have any ideas?

Comment: may be its only me with the thought , but what exactly do you want to say here ??

Comment: sorry for my English, my question is that, how the other java application could handle the previous "console", for example, the first application waiting for input from "console", how can we input the value, such as " 1+1", by the other java application, instead of inputing by keyword; 2. the output should be 2, which will be displayed in console, how could the output will be received by other java application. just like there are some Api of "console", console.input="1+1", and output=console.output. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can run two applications at the same time using using the console. If you look in the console pane, there's a button on the top right that looks like a little compute monitor (Display Selected Console). When running two applications, you can toggle the console view for each application.

Comment: thanks for your answer, my question is that, how the other java application could handle the previous "console", for example, the first application waiting for input from "console", how can we input the value, such as " 1+1", by the other java application, instead of inputing by keyword; 2. the output should be 2, which will be displayed in console, how could the output will be received by other java application.  just like there are some Api of "console", console.input="1+1", and output=console.output.  thanks

Comment: You could write a server program that listens on a port. Other that, honestly, I'm not sure.